# Deleting layers from QGIS interface?

Tags: qgis-3

I'm working on a QGIS3 plugin and having problems deleting layers (from previous run of the plugin) from the main interface. I have two layers - a user supplied input polygon file and a plugin generated output polygon file.
It works the first time I run it, and loads the layers as expected. However, when I try to run interface_clean() to remove the previous versions of the layers, I get

> [2019-06-10 16:01:13.503881] font color="orange"[warn] Could not
>   load selection in layer
>
> [2019-06-10 16:01:13.534769] font color="red"[Unexpected error] File "change_mapper.py", line 790, in run
>       self.interface_clean()

Followed by a class RuntimeError

> wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer
>   has been deleted

The layer names disappears from the Layers Tab but the vectors are continuing still to be visible in the display. 
I assume I am making a horrible error in my coding.

Can anyone help?

To display vector objects

```
def display_input_vector_object(self):

    # Load vector object into main window
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.vector_file_obj)

    # Set layer colour to be purple
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()
    symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
    symbol.setColor(QColor(142,0,142,85))
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    self.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())


def display_final_vector_object(self):

    self.current_layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(self.out_vectorFilename, self.displayName, "ogr")
    if not self.IndexIncrease:
        land_class = {                                                              # Create dictionary to store 'attribute value' : ('symbol colour', 'legend name')
            '0': ('#0f0', ''),
            '1': ('#ff0000', 'Significant Negative Change')
        }
    else:
        land_class = {                                                              # Create dictionary to store 'attribute value' : ('symbol colour', 'legend name')
            '0': ('#0f0', ''),
            '1': ('#00ff00', 'Significant Positive Change')
        }

    categories = []                                                             # Create list to store symbology properties
    for classes, (color, label) in land_class.items():                          # Iterate through the dictionary
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(self.current_layer.geometryType())          # Automatically set symbols based on layer's geometry
        symbol.setColor(QColor(color))                                          # Set colour
        if classes == '0':                                                      # Set symbol with value = 0 to be transparent
            symbol.setOpacity(0)
        category = QgsRendererCategory(classes, symbol, label)                  # Set the renderer properties
        categories.append(category)

    expression = 'DN'                                                           # Field name 
    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories)             # Set the categorized renderer
    self.current_layer.setRenderer(renderer)
    self.current_layer.triggerRepaint()                                              # Refresh layer
```

To clear vector objects

```
def interface_clean(self):

    # Check for any previous versions of files in interface.

    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    for layer in layers:
        if (layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer):
            if (layer.name() == "User selected input polygons"):
                QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
            if (self.displayName in layer.name()):
                QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
```

I do not understand why I am getting a complaint about loading files when I'm trying to remove them.

Can anyone see anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Taking a bit of a guess here... How are you calling your `interface_clean` function? Is it by any chance from a button in your plugin dialog? If so, make sure to connect the `button.clicked` signal to your function slot in the `initGui` method NOT the `run` method. Connecting signals to slots in the run method without disconnecting them is a likely source of deleted C++ object errors.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for the suggestion. I am calling interface_clean() directly from the run method. It is not connected to any of the gui. Are you saying it would be better in initGui?

Comment: No, it was just unclear how it was being called. I thought you might have had a signal/ slot connection in the run method which was not being disconnected. The problem is not obvious to me. Someone else may know. Posting more of your code may help too.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - I found the problem. In `interface_clean()` I made mistake with the code. It should read

```
def interface_clean(self):

    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    print(' Checking existing layers in interface for unwanted files')
    print('displayName is ',self.displayName)
    for layer in layers:
        if (layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer):
            print('layer name is : ',layer.name())
            if (layer.name() == "User selected input polygons" or self.displayName in layer.name()):
                QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
```

The original version was crashing as, in second if clause, it was looking for a layer that had already been deleted in the first if clause. Stupid mistake on my part. Fixed now.